# Example uses of MSets in Coq

Tags: set, coq

[`MSets`](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.MSets.MSets.html) appear to be the way to go for OCaml-style finite sets. Sadly, I can't find example uses.

How can I define an empty `MSet` or a singleton `MSet`? How can I union two `MSets` together?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me show a simple example for finite sets of natural numbers:

```
From Coq
Require Import MSets Arith.

(* We can make a set out of an ordered type *)
Module S := Make Nat_as_OT.

Definition test := S.union (S.singleton 42)
                           (S.empty).

(* membership *)
Compute S.mem 0 test.   (* evaluates to `false` *)
Compute S.mem 42 test.  (* evaluates to `true`  *)

Compute S.is_empty test.     (* evaluates to `false` *)
Compute S.is_empty S.empty.  (* evaluates to `true` *)
```

You can read [`Coq.MSets.MSetInterface`](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.MSets.MSetInterface.html) to discover the  operations and specifications `MSet`s provide.

Comment: Thanks a lot!

The requirement that we work with an `OrderedType` is maybe a bit obnoxious, are there no formulations of sets which rely on typeclasses instead?

Comment: You can check the MathClasses library which is based on typecalsses, see e.g. [here](https://github.com/math-classes/math-classes/blob/751e63b260bd2f78b280f2566c08a18034bd40b3/interfaces/finite_sets.v)

Comment: Sorry to resurrect this, but how might I do this Strings? Although the `From Coq.Structures.OrderedTypeEx` has a String_as_OT item in it, but if I try to substitute it into your code above I get the following error: `Error: The field eq_equiv is missing in Coq.Structures.OrderedTypeEx.String_as_OT.`. For that matter, importing the `OrderedTypeEx` module above breaks your code as well. I can see that the module doesn't have the needed item, but I'm unsure of what I need to do to fix it. Related question: if I had a `Definition var := nat.
`, how could I make a set of "var"s?

Comment: Looks like you would need to use `Update_OT` functor, e.g. `Module String_as_OT := Update_OT String_as_OT.
Module Str := Make String_as_OT.`