# How to make a finite set type using MSets with the "usual" equality?

Tags: set, coq

I'm sorry to ask a simple question but I've been looking for an answer for hours and I haven't found an explanation that's simple enough for me (I don't really understand Coq's module system)

I have the following types

```
Def var := nat.

Inductive type : Type :=
| Unit
| Arrow (a : type) (b : type)
| Ref (a : type)
.

Inductive Judgement : Type :=
| judge (v : var) (t : type)
.
```

I would like to be able to make (finite) sets of `Judgements`. From the research I've done it looks like [MSets](https://coq.github.io/doc/master/stdlib/Coq.MSets.MSetInterface.html) are what I want. In particular I (think that I) am interested in the "Weak" sets, as I'd like to avoid having to leverage the ordered-ness of `var/nat`. However for the life of me, I can't figure out how can actually create the type corresponding to a set of Judgements.

The closest example I've been able to find is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44793027/example-uses-of-msets-in-coq), but I'd like to be able to make sets of unordered elements

Answer (score 0):

Can't you work around this by using a list of judgments rather than an MSet of judgments?

Using MSets involves defining an ordered type, which might be quite a bit of boilerplate.

See the example of [nats in the standard libraries Nat_as_OT](https://coq.github.io/doc/master/stdlib/Coq.Structures.OrderedTypeEx.html#Nat_as_OT)

```
Module Nat_as_OT <: UsualOrderedType.

  Definition t := nat.

  Definition eq := @eq nat.
  Definition eq_refl := @eq_refl t.
  Definition eq_sym := @eq_sym t.
  Definition eq_trans := @eq_trans t.

  Definition lt := lt.

  Lemma lt_trans : forall x y z : t, lt x y -> lt y z -> lt x z.

  Lemma lt_not_eq : forall x y : t, lt x y -> ~ eq x y.

  Definition compare x y : Compare lt eq x y.

  Definition eq_dec := eq_nat_dec.

End Nat_as_OT.
```

Comment: Well defining sets as lists would hardly seem to be less boilerplate, as I would have to define all the operations and propositions myself, no? Furthermore it already seems possible to use MSets with unordered types (check out MSetWeakList for example), and I`d like to be able to do this

Comment: Then the answer still stands: you need to create a module representing judgment. In the case of MSetWeakList you need to give a [DecidableType](https://coq.github.io/doc/master/stdlib/Coq.Structures.Equalities.html#DecidableType) instead.

Comment: I've actually been trying that for the last hour without success: I'm very new to Coq, so I don't know anything about the module system. Could you please show me how to make a `DecideableType` for `Judgement`?

Comment: Have you looked at https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Lists.ListSet.html ?

Comment: I would like to make use of the `MSet` interface, which provides a lot of useful types which I've been using